# Android - How to decide which architecture fits better the application requirements

Tags: android, model-view-controller, mvvm, architecture, mvp

I am asking this question in order to know how does the community chooses the right architecture for every project in android platform so I can have a better idea if I am on the right path or not.
I am already an experienced developer and I have experienced and implemented most of the Android's major architecture patterns (i.e: MVC, MVP, MVVM ...).

My question is how, as an Android developer or Android applications architect, I get to decide on which architectural pattern I should build my next app on based on the app requirements between MVC, MVP and MVVM.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://academy.realm.io/posts/eric-maxwell-mvc-mvp-and-mvvm-on-android/

Answer (score 6):

Well, here's how I do it:

- MVC: If you're talking about using just plain and simple Activities and Fragments in your App, withouth Dagger, without any DI, without layers, I wouldn't recommend this at any point. Unless your App is just one Activity and one screen, you should always use an architecture that splits your App into layers. The old-school Android MVC architecture built just with the classes from the SDK isn't fit unless you're building a really **really** small project.
- MVP: Nowadays the MVP architecture is one of the most stable architectures out there, there's not much second guessing when implementing it, It's already well defined everywhere. In a nutshell you just need your UI (Fragment/Activity), the View interface that is going to be implemented in that UI and the one that is going to be used as callback from the Presenter, the Presenter's interface, the Presenter's implementation, the Repositories, the Repositories interfaces and the UseCases or Interactors. Everything in a MVP architecture is very well defined, all the layers are separated one from another and the communication mechanism is usually done through callback interfaces.
- MVVM: It's definitely the architecture that is gonna be used by default in the future (I think 1 year tops). We got rid of a lot of boilerplate code with the MVVM architecture. The communication between layers is much more simple by using LiveData. There's no need to define 500 components when creating a new screen, like in the MVP.
- Multi module architecture vs single module architecture: Both MVVM and MVP can implement **multi module** architectures or single module architectures. I think that this choice It's even more important than choosing between MVVM and MVP. If you know that your App is going to have a large and complex business logic, let's say a social network App of some kind, then you should use a multi module architecture, this is going to allow you to keep the features separated into modules, the building time (if the module references and the dependency injection is properly done) is going to be linear-ish and It's going to help you to work comfortably with your team. If you pick a **single module** architecture, you need to keep in mind that the building time is going to increase as you add new libraries and new features. If you know that the project isn't complex enough for a multi module architecture, then this is you right choice. And you always can turn your single module project into a multi module project if you keep your class well organized under a MVP/MVVM architecture.

I've worked in projects where I choose a multi module architecture right off the bat, because I knew that the project was going to have a lot of features. But my first idea is always using a MVP architecture, single module with Kotlin, you can always move your project to a multi module architecture if you keep your classes well organized.

MVVM is really good as well, but I've never worked in a project using a multi module architecture with MVVM, I'm not sure if having changes in the UI's xml with Databinding would mess with other devs working on the project. I still need to try it.

TL;DR: MVP is the best choice for now, remember to keep all your architectural components nice and tidy, each one with its interface and its implementation separated. MVVM is definitely the future but I wouldn't use it for a large multi module project, if you use it for a single module project is perfectly okay.

Check out my repo if you want to see some architectural examples:

http://www.github.com/4gus71n

Lemme know if you have any other question.

Comment: Thank you so much for you insights about architectural patterns used in android Development. I am pretty convinced that MVP is the most stable and mature Architectural Pattern used in Android! Also I am quite convinced that MVVM is gaining attraction over MVP.

Comment: Hence, what do you think about my thoughts so far:

• If Views are passives (they serves as a presentation layer to the model without any UI logic and very few model manipulations) then MVVM would fit better as changes that occur in the model (Business layer) are reflected to the view automatically and the view does nothing but to display the data and communicate user interactions through the ViewModel.

• If the app has lot of interaction between View and business logic I would go for MVP!

Comment: Yeah, that's a good way to think about it. Think about the whole process of validating a form-like screen. Imagine that you have a screen that is basically the user profile data, you have the user's avatar, profile name, address, etc. With MVVM the form validation, to check non-empty strings and stuff like that can be done fairly simple. With MVP you are going to have to code those validations into the Presenter logic.

Comment: But I always try to think the architecture design in terms of how well the rest of the team is going to work with that architecture. MVVM can lead to some conflicts when changing Databinding code in the XML, errors when changing ViewModel code. Lots of stuff in the MVVM like the Databinding communication with the ViewModel is done "magically" and there's no warnings whatsoever if you change a line in the XML.

Comment: Sharp!!! Every single architecture has it's pros and cons. My self I am advocating mixing architectures based on the need of the UI and/or model layer. This choice can lead to conflicts with the team but it definitely won't if the app has a Multi-Module taste, as each module can leverage the best fitting architecture as needed. Hence if modules are very small sized then developers won't add extra complexity to the feature just to align with overall architecture.